# Запросы в TFS API C#

Tags: c#, запрос, tfs

Мне необходимо получить список тест кейсов из запроса в TFS.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("server_address"));
ITestManagementService testMangementService = (ITestManagementService)tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
ITestManagementTeamProject testManagementTeamProject = testMangementService.GetTeamProject("project_name");
```

Далее я получаю список всех запросов

```
IList<ITestCaseQuery> testCaseQuery = testManagementTeamProject.Queries;
```

Затем получаю список тест кейсов в запросе

```
List<ITestCase> testCaseList = testManagement.TestCases.Query(testCaseQuery["selected_query"].QueryText).ToList();
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если Type of Query - Flat list of work items, то я получаю все тест кейсы в запросе, а если Type of Query - Work items and direct link или Tree of work items, то выдает исключение: "TF248021: You have specifeid a query string that is not valid when you use the query method for a flat list of work items. You cannot specify a parametrized query or a query string for linked work items with the query method you specified." Если тип запроса "Flat list of work items", то строка запроса будет такой: "select [System.Id], ... from WorkItems ...", а если - "Work items and direct link" или "Tree of work items", то такой: "select [System.Id], ... from WorkItemLinks ..." Такое происходит, если я в запрос, помимо тест кейсов, добавляю Product Backlog Item.

Насчет значения поля testCaseQuery["selected_query"].QueryText. 
Если значение поля:

> "select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject]=@project and ([System.WorkItemType]='Test Case'  and [System.Title] contains words 'new' or [System.WorkItemType]='Product Backlog Item')"
>    то все работает. А если значение:
>
> "select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItemLinks where (Source.[System.TeamProject]=@project and (Source.[System.WorkItemType]='Test Case' or Source.[System.WorkItemType]='Task' or Source.[System.WorkItemType]='Feature')) and ([System.Links.LinkType]='System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') and (Target.[System.TeamProject]=@project and Target.[System.WorkItemType]<>") mode (Recursive)"

то выдает исключение.

Comment: так а в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я могу получить список тест кейсов только если тип запроса "Flat list of work items", а мне необходимо и при других типах запроса. Т.е. если тип запроса, допустим, Work items and direct link и в этом запросе есть тест кейсы, то я получу исключение.

Comment: вы пишете, что получаете исключение, но не приводите никакой информации про это исключение, ни сообщение исключения, ни стек, ничего. А сам факт наличия исключения без его описания бесполезен.

Comment: вот [rest api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20cases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) к TFS, вот [клиентские либы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops), вы это использовали? Или что? Какая версия TFS?

Comment: Я получаю исключение: "TF248021: You have specifeid a query string that is not valid when you use the query method for a flat list of work items. You cannot specify a parametrized query or a query string for linked work items with the query method you specified."

Если тип запроса "Flat list of work items", то строка запроса будет такой: "select [System.Id], ... from WorkItems ...", 
а если - "Work items and direct link" или "Tree of work items", то такой: "select [System.Id], ... from WorkItemLinks ..."
Такое происходит, если я в запрос, помимо тест кейсов, добавляю Product Backlog Item

Comment: хорошо, теперь читаем ещё раз текст ошибки: `You have specifeid a query string that is not valid when you use the query method for a flat list of work items. You cannot specify a parametrized query or a query string for linked work items with the query method you specified.` - что конкретно из этого текста не понятно? Здесь говорится о `query string` и `query method`, которые вы нигде не привели. То, что вы привели в комментарии - это не `query string`, это цитата из него, которая может имеет отношение к ошибке, а может и нет.

Comment: и ещё - дополняйте свой вопрос этими сведениями, вы можете же его редактировать. А комментарии мало кто будет читать, чтобы понять, где же у вас проблема.

Comment: Про query stirng, то в коде это: "testCaseQuery["selected_query"].QueryText"

Comment: вот это `testCaseQuery["selected_query"].QueryText` - какое значение у этого поля?

Comment: В этом поле строка с запросом, например: "select [System.Id], ... from WorkItems ...". Т.е. значение зависит от выбранного запроса.

Comment: не надо никаких `например`, мой вопрос - какая именно там строка в тот момент, когда вы получаете исключение? У вас же ошибка в запросе - вам это явно написано в тексте ошибки, потому я и спрашиваю - что именно вы отправляете в этом запросе? без угадаек, ставьте точку останова, смотрите значение поля, или запускайте фиддлер и ловите трафик, какой конкретно запрос уходит на сервер - этим и дополняйте вопрос.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Я бы посоветовал убирать из `WorkItemLinks` запроса условия до тех пор, пока он не заработает. Та вы поймете что в запросе ему не нравится. Также проверьте, пройдет ли вот такой простой запрос без фильтров? `select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItemLinks`

Comment: @tym32167 <offtop>хвала твоему терпению :)</offtop>

Comment: @XelaNimed  годы практики :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле не очень понятно зачем выполняется отбор тест-кейсов через клиент testManagement. Для того, чтобы отбирать айтемы в любом виде, используюется WorkItem Client. При этом результат выполнения флет-листа и результата со ссылками разный. Простой список содержит список айтем, а дерево или ссылки содержит структуру линков в виде Source->Target. Для построения правильного запроса рекомендую в VS сначал создать запрос снеобходимыми условиями, а сохранить его не в тфс, а на локальный диск. Там будет виден правильно сконструированный wiql запрос.

Примеры запуска запросов:

1. Простой список:

   ```
   private static void GetTasksWithWIQL(WorkItemStore pWiStore)
   {
       List<WorkItem> _parents = new List<WorkItem>();

       string _wiql = String.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE ([System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') ORDER BY [System.Id]");

       Query _query = new Query(pWiStore, _wiql);

       WorkItemCollection _wis = _query.RunQuery();

       for (int i = 0; i < _wis.Count; i++)
           Console.WriteLine("Work item: {0}:{1}:{2}", _wis[i].Type.Name, _wis[i].Id, _wis[i].Title);              
   }
   ```
2. Список со ссылками:

   ```
   private static void GetParentsWithWIQL(WorkItemStore pWiStore)
   {

       string _wiql = String.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story') And ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(Recursive,ReturnMatchingChildren)");

       Query _query = new Query(pWiStore, _wiql);

       WorkItemLinkInfo[] _links = _query.RunLinkQuery();

       for (int i = 0; i < _links.Count(); i++)
           if (_links[i].SourceId == 0) Console.WriteLine("This is top level {1}", _links[i].SourceId, _links[i].TargetId);
           else
               Console.WriteLine("Parent - {0}; Child - {1}", _links[i].SourceId, _links[i].TargetId);

   }
   ```
3. Получение теста через рабочий элемент:

   ```
   private static void GetTests(WorkItemStore pWiStore, string pTeamProjectName)
   {
       ITestManagementTeamProject _testProject = pWiStore.TeamProjectCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>().GetTeamProject(pTeamProjectName);

       string _wiql = String.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case'  And [System.TeamProject] = '{0}' ORDER BY [System.Id]", pTeamProjectName);

       Query _query = new Query(pWiStore, _wiql);

       var _wis = _query.RunQuery();

       for (int i = 0; i < _wis.Count; i++)
           if (_wis[i].Type.Name == "Test Case")
           {
               var _testCaseToEdit = _testProject.TestCases.Find(_wis[i].Id);

               //edit test case here
           }
   }
   ```

Comment: А как из WorkItem с типом Test Case получить Actions, которые содержатся в этом тест кейсе?

Comment: @ivanpupkin Через метод TestCases.Find(ID) можно получить тест. Ответ обновил.

Comment: Получилось, всем спасибо)